# Hive/SQL queries for funnel analysis.

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, avro

I need to perform funnel analysis on a data the schema for which is following:

```
A(int X) Matched_B(int[] Y) Filtered_C(int[] Z)
```

Where,

- `A` refers to client ID which can send multiple requests. Instead of storing request ID only client ID is being stored per request in the data pipeline. (I don't know why)
- `Matched_B` refers to a list of items returned for a query.
- `Flitered_C` is a subset of `Matched_B` and refers to items which successfully passed the filter.

All the data is stored in avro files in HDFS. The QPS with which data is being stored in HDFS is around 12000.

I need to prepare the following reports:

- For each combination of `(X,Y[i])`, the number of times `Y[i]` appears in `Matched_B`.
- For each combination of `(X,Y[i])`, the number of times `Y[i]` appears in `Filtered_C`.

Basically I would like to know whether this task can be performed using Hive only?

Currently, I am thinking of the following architecture.

```
HDFS(avro_schema)--> Hive_Script_1 --> HDFS(avro_schema_1) --> Java Application --> HDFS(avro_schema_2) --> Hive_Script_2(external_table) --> result
```

Where,

- `avro_schema` is the schema described above.
- `avro_schema_1` is generated by `Hive_Script_1` by transforming (using `Lateral View explode(Matched_B`)) `avro_schema` and is described as follows:

`A(int X) Matched_B_1(int Y) Filtered_C(int[] Z)`

- `avro_schema_2` is generated by the Java Application and is described as follows:

`A(int X) Matched_B(int Y) Matched_Y(1 if Y is matched, else 0) Filtered_Y(1 if Y is filtered, 0 otherwise)`

Finally we can run a Hive script to process this data for events generated each day.

The other architecture could be that we remove `avro_schema_1` generation and directly process `avro_schema` from the Java application and generate the result.

However, I would like to avoid writing a Java application for this task. Could some point me to a Hive solution to the above problem?

Would also like some architecture's POV regarding the efficient solution to this problem.

Note: Kindly suggest the solution taking into account the QPS(12000).